# Trouble reading data from client to server

Tags: c

I am having trouble reading values from a client from my server/client program. User are supposed to enter a country in the client and the server are supposed to process the value and then return the information (capital, currency) related to the country.

For my program, the server is able to return the correct data for the first time. For example, user key in China, the server will return the capital as beijing etc..

However, when the user entered for example 'Germany' for the second time, the server does not return any data at all.

Hope you guys can identify the error in my codes. Thanks in advance!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have exhausted all your debugging options already? Debugging is a valuable skill to gain experience in and should not be outsourced to Stackoverflow lightly. For example, have you run the server and client in a debugger and/or added in more debugging statements? A simple data point which you haven't shared with us for example is whether the server correctly receives the second request. If so, does it send the right response the second time, and so on in the debugging steps.

Comment: Well, the 'while (1)' loop in the client cannot return more than one result from the server - you explicitly close the client socket: 'close(clientFd);', after receiving the first result.  That is something that you really should have noticed while stepping through the client code with your debugger, as suggested by @kaylum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *client* side, after printing received answer you're closing `clientFd` and not trying to reconnect for further use. In fact for second time `write` is doing on a closed file descriptor. One solution is this:

```
while (1) {
    /* Create a socket, bidirectional, default protocol */
    clientFd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);

    do { /* Loop until a connection is made with the server */
        result = connect(clientFd, serverSockAddrPtr, serverLen);
        printf("Attempting to connect...\n");
        if (result == -1) sleep(1); /* Wait and then try again */
    } while (result == -1);

    char country[300];

    printf("%s \n", " ");
    printf("Please enter country > ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(country, sizeof(country), stdin);
    printf("%s \n", " ");

    if (0 == strcmp(country, "end\n")) {
        printf("Thank you for using country services\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        write(clientFd, country, strlen(country));
        parse(clientFd);
    }

    close(clientFd);
    printf("%d\n", clientFd);
    clientFd = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Deeply appreciated!